# Convert Curl to wp_remote_post bitaps api

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I have to convert this curl into wp_remote_post.

```
 function post_api($url, $postfields) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    return $result;
  }
$postfields = json_encode(array('redeemcode'=> $redeemcode));
$data = post_api("https://bitaps.com/api/get/redeemcode/info", $postfields);
```

I tried this one but getting error..... Jason Decode error.

```
    $data = wp_remote_post( "https://bitaps.com/api/get/redeemcode/info", array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'timeout' => 45,
            'redirection' => 5,
            'httpversion' => '1.0',
            'blocking' => true,
            'headers' => array(),
            'body' => $postfields,
            'cookies' => array()
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

curl response as JSON data & wp_remote_post() gives array formated data.
so use error function to identify the error or positive response & if received error then use wp_remote_retrieve_body(). this will might be work.

Ex.

```html
if( is_wp_error( $data ) ) {
 return false;
}

$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $data );

$data = json_decode( $body );
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass $redeemcode with a correct value.

You can use following for example:

```
 $redeemcode = "BTCuoC8AGRbHjEss347c4KoQrdzqyJwDSdAxbjAoC4tyAbxTAhBuq";
```

**Result**:

```
[body] => {"balance": 0, "paid_out": 0, "pending_balance": 0, "address": "17BcAXNkpVKCrAAVKDr4CXDHLhXv9gTVY7"}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i got my answer now here is all code i used for the others to help.

```
         function post_api($url, $postfields) {
                $data = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    'timeout' => 45,
                    'redirection' => 5,
                    'httpversion' => '1.0',
                    'blocking' => true,
                    'headers' => array(),
                    'body' => $postfields,
                    'cookies' => array()
                    )
                );
                    if( is_wp_error( $data ) ) {
                        return false;
                    }

            $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $data );   

            return $body;
        }
        $postfields = json_encode(array('redeemcode'=> $redeemcode));
        $data = post_api("https://bitaps.com/api/get/redeemcode/info", $postfields);
```